# Azure Blob Storage Container to Disk

Tags: azure

I want to upload a VHD to a container in Azure Blob Storage. I want to copy the VHD to a data disk in Azure, so that I may select it under Server 2016 for remote desktop services.

Do I need to upload a VHD to a container in Blob Storage, and then export the VHD from the container in Blob Storage via Powershell to the data disk?

Comment: Not 100% what you are looking for... Do you want to upload the VHD and build a VM from it or simply attach it as a data disk to an existing VM?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to upload a VHD to a container in Blob Storage, and then
>   export the VHD from the container in Blob Storage via Powershell to
>   the data disk?

You should upload VHD to Azure storage blob container, then copy the VHD(two vhds).

You just need to use one VHD to create new VM, then attach another VHD to the new VM as the data disk. You can read data from that disk directly.